# How to make gridview show the all data column within templated fields?

Tags: asp.net

I have a project in Asp.net that someone insert data into a SQL Server database, and when he wants to recall the latest inserted data (for this item I have written a stored procedure so I will use it in gridview) he has to press a button that a gridview to show them all.

In the gridview I would like to add my own template(because i have some items as well as Jquery Calendar which has to be added by myself) and bind it to server and select stored procedure to read it. So the code I have to read data from DB is here:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlDataReader dr = DataProvider.ExecuteDataReader("[dbo].[Get_LastIdHowzeEducationFinishDate_SP]", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        GridView1.DataSource = dr;

        SqlDataReader dr2 = DataProvider.ExecuteDataReader("[dbo].[Get_LastIdHowzeEducationField_SP]", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        GridView1.DataSource = dr2;
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

but I don't know why only one of them is shown (the second one) meanwhile I want to show some other data column inside gridview.

This is the first stored procedure I wrote:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_LastInsertedRowHowzeEducation_SP]
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT
        he.FieldName as 'رشته تحصیلی',
        he.SchoolName as 'نام موسسه آموزشی',
        he.StudyCityDescribtion as 'محل تحصیل',
        he.Average as 'معدل',
        he.ThesisTitle as 'عنوان پایان نامه',
        he.Describtion as 'توضیحات' 
    FROM
        PersonHowEducation prh 
    INNER JOIN
        HowzeEducation he ON prh.HowzeEducationId = he.HowzeEducationId
    WHERE
        prh.IdCode = (SELECT IdCode FROM Persons 
                      WHERE IdCode = IDENT_CURRENT('persons'))
END
```

but by this code I can not add the Jquery Calendar into the gridview, so I decided to separated them and for each column write a procedure and to recall them inside the gridview by select statement and within gridview templated fields.these are two of separated stored procedures :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_LastIdHowzeEducationFinishDate_SP]

AS
BEGIN 
select he.FinishLevelDate as 'تاریخ اتمام سطح'
   from PersonHowEducation prh inner join HowzeEducation he on 
          prh.HowzeEducationId=he.HowzeEducationId
          where prh.IdCode=
          (Select IdCode from Persons where IdCode=IDENT_CURRENT('persons'))

END
```

and the other:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_LastInsertedRowHowzeEducation_SP]

AS
BEGIN 
select he.FieldName as 'رشته تحصیلی',he.SchoolName as 'نام موسسه آموزشی',
   he.StudyCityDescribtion as 'محل تحصیل',he.Average as 'معدل',
   he.ThesisTitle as 'عنوان پایان نامه',
   he.Describtion as 'توضیحات' 
   from PersonHowEducation prh inner join HowzeEducation he on 
          prh.HowzeEducationId=he.HowzeEducationId
          where prh.IdCode=
          (Select IdCode from Persons where IdCode=IDENT_CURRENT('persons'))

END
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one is shown because you are overwriting the first datasource when you go `GridView1.DataSource = dr2;`

Comment: I know that, but i want to make both of them visible.i mean to how can i show both of them or even more number of procedrues to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

In general a GridView should be used for a single set of data.  If you want to show multiple sets of data, you should use multiple GridViews or you *could* use a UNION to connect the data or nest GridViews, but that really just complicates the setup.

If you post a little more information about what you are trying to do, or the stored procedures you are using, we might be able to be more help.

Comment: ok. i will edit my question in above an i add my stored procedures,and the rest of my codes.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you are trying to do in the GV and why you needed to separate the SPs to utilize a Jquery calendar. I am not aware of a way to use 2 SPs to populate a GV short of creating a single Generic List of objects that populates manually from the two stored procedures and a datareader.